# Does the zombie lord from haunt 21 take damage from a sanity roll?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

We were playing Haunt 21 and I was the zombie lord. My friend had the Ring and the Medallion and decided to use the Ring to attack me with Sanity. Would the zombie lord take damage or be stunned from the attack?

We decided to just make it take damage but I wasn't aware that they could just kill the zombie lord in order to win. It was a close game regardless but it would be nice for some clarification. (The difference in Sanity was their 7 to my 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would take damage.

Normally, you cannot damage a monster unless the specific rules for the haunt say otherwise). Under the normal rules:

> If a monster suffers
>   any damage, it is stunned and misses its next turn.

However, the Haunt 21 rules makes an exception to this, it says that while holding the Medallion, you can damage the Zombie Lord. It does not specify anything about physical vs mental damage; so it will just be damage either way.

From the traitor's rulebook:

> The Zombie Lord can be damaged only by
>   an explorer holding the Medallion. Instead
>   of being stunned, you can take 7 points of
>   damage before you are killed. Use the
>   Turn/Damage Track to record damage.
>   Damage does not reduce your traits.

Comment: It could be up to 14 points of damage given the OP's description. Unless I'm missing something. I don't think the "instead of being stunned" means that the zombie lord only takes 1 pt of damage max per round.

Comment: @ikegami, I'm not sure I understand. The player in question was holding the medallion, so "can only be damaged only by an explorer holding the Medallion" seems clearly fulfilled. And I don't see how it could be 14 points of damage, the traitor's rules clearly state that after 7 points of damage, you lose.

Comment: I never said or implied that there was any limit to how much damage per round the zombie lord can take...

Comment: @Red_Shadow, I see I now that I made a mistake. I forgot that damage amount is winner's stat minus loser's stat, not just 1 point. I didn't mean to imply there was a 1 point limit of damage. Edited.

Comment: @GendoIkari I think what the OP listed was the stat differences. You roll a number of dice equal tot he stat and they have 0, 1, and 2-pip faces. So the minimum roll of 2 dice is 0 and the max roll of 7 dice is 14, hence a max of 14 damage per round.

Comment: @ikegami I see no reason that "how" would be any different than the way you always damage anything throughout the game, whether it's a monster or another player. You damage him by attacking him. The ring allows you to attack with sanity instead of might; it's still a regular attack aside from that.

Comment: @ikegami The Zombie Lord takes damage like a player, but it is marked on the damage track, and his stats are not reduced. He does not use the general Zombie rules.

Comment: @ikegami, All monsters can take damage like normal, unless their rules state otherwise. The effects of that damage are different for monsters than for players (they are stunned). But unless a monster has special rules, it would take damage like normal. The zombie lord has 1 special rule about how it can take damage; which is that the player needs to have the medallion.

Comment: I am convinced. The wording of the rules was different than what I had in my head.